# Can I sync a Guitar Hero World Tour controller dongle with a Guitar Hero 3 guitar?

Tags: pc, controllers, guitar-hero

So, I was curious, can I sync this controller dongle (that little thing, not the guitar itself): [image: guitar hero controller:]

with this guitar? [image: this guitar].

I want to play Frets on Fire with this guitar on the PC with this set but I can't sync them.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a while back when I moved house and had a few different GH controllers and it was hell trying to find which dongle went with what guitar. So basically, you can't do it.

A GH dongle will only sync to the type of guitar controller it's made for, at least in my own experiences.

Answer (score 1):

The PS3 guitars for Guitar Hero World Tour and Guitar Hero 3 use the same communication standard, and their dongles *are* interchangeable.

**However**, please note that Guitar Hero 5 and Band Hero use a very similar style of dongle and guitar to World Tour, which are *not* cross-compatible with the earlier ones.

---

#### Identification

- The GH3 Les Paul guitar dongle (guitar pick shape) has model number 95121.806 ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryNtz.jpg), [label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWR7r.png)).
- The GHWT PS3 dongle has model number 95451.806 ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmlHn.png)*, [label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5GeD.png)).
- The GH5/Band Hero PS2 & PS3 dongle has model number 95893.806 ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLjcp.jpg)*, [label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfwdX.jpg)).

And to recap, of these items, the GH3 and GHWT receivers for PS3 are freely interchangeable. Neither one will work in place of a GH5/Band Hero dongle, nor vice versa. The Wii and Xbox models do not use these dongles, and the PS2 model will not work with the PS3 receiver.

*In addition to the obvious differences found on the label (model number, product description, etc.), which may not be visible on some internet item listings, note the updated Guitar Hero logo — the GH5 logo uses a simpler design, with slightly more uniform letters, and a straight-legged R (versus the curve of the R in the logo of earlier games).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use "Xpadder", it is a software that detects all the buttons of a projection device or hardware, then asignas to each button found a key on the keyboard (obviously). In any case, there are many tutorials to configure XPADDER on Youtube. I see you use it for the PC game called FoF, as I explain a bit why is not supported when using both guitars. You see, the first image samples is the GHWT guitar and the second is that of GH3. You see, not is if you asked (if is played GH on PS2 ever without guitar) of the "why do I in GHWT is not supported without the guitar?" i.e. can not play the game without the guitar as well as the GH3 or its predecessors. It is simple, this is due to changes in terms or actions for each button of the guitar, I mean, GH3 guitar is supposed that "Green" is "L2", "Red" is "L1", "Yellow" is "R1", "Blue" is "R2" and "Orange" is "▲". But this changes on the GHWT guitars since its keys are different actions.